# Make sub menus expandable using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am working on a navigation menu with nested sub menus. I was wondering if there is a way I can achieve the menus to be expandable when I click the parent menu item

This is my HTML code, as you guys can see I have 2 ng-repeat inside the parent menu item and another one if the sub menu item has one or more sub menus

```html
<div id="sidebar-wrapper" ng-controller="navigationController" style="overflow-y: auto; margin-top:-20px;" class="hidden-print" ng-hide="hideSidebar()">
  <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-bigfont" style="border-width: 0">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <li class="portal-text-19b" ng-repeat="item in newMenu" ng-class="{active: hightlight === item.title && item.path !== '#'}" ng-show="showItem(item.path, item.allowAll)">
        <a style="text-transform: uppercase" href="{{item.path}}" ng-click="item.fn()">
          <span class="{{item.icon}}"></span>&nbsp; {{item.title}}
          <span style="font-size: 7px;" ng-if="item.childs" class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li style="list-style-type: none;" ng-repeat="child in item.childs" ng-class="{active: hightlight === child.title && child.path !== '#'}" ng-show="showItem(child.path, child.allowAll)">
            <a href="{{child.path}}" ng-click="child.fn()">
              <span class="{{child.icon}}"></span>&nbsp; {{child.title}}
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
              <li style="list-style-type: none;" ng-repeat="child2 in child.childs" ng-class="{active: hightlight === child2.title && child2.path !== '#'}" ng-show="showItem(child2.path, child2.allowAll)">
                <a href="{{child2.path}}" ng-click="child2.fn()">
                  <span class="{{child2.icon}}"></span>&nbsp; {{child2.title}}
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the inner `ul` elements as hidden, and then use the following code to show/hide them:

```
$("ul li").has("ul").click(function() {
  $(this).find("ul").toggle();
});
```

This will toggle hiding and showing the sub `ul` elements on their parent `li` click.

**Explanation:**

It uses [**.has()** method](https://api.jquery.com/has/) to attach the `click` event handler to only `li` having `ul` children, and [**.toggle()** method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to show/hide the child list of the clicked `li` element.

**Demo:**

This is a working Demo Snippet:

```js
$("ul li").has("ul").click(function() {
  $(this).find("ul").toggle();
});
```

```css
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2
    <ul>
      <li>list item 2-a</li>
      <li>list item 2-b</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: using angularjs?

Comment: @Leandro Yes of course, angularjs is built on jQuery.